How to change email for firebase users?
Now that updateEmail is deprecated for updating the Firebase user's email, how to update the user's email?
 final user = GetCurrentUser().getUser()!;

  AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    email: oldEmail,
    password: password,
  );



  final UserCredential userAuth = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
  // userAuth.user.updateEmail(newEmail);  // deprecated


  await userAuth.user?.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(newEmail);

  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update(
    {
      "email": newEmail,
    },
  );

This is what I got so far. It worked one time for unknown magical reasons, but never since. I'm getting an exception that the user cannot be found. Other times, I'm getting an update to the Firestore field (meaning the code runs without exceptions), but the Firebase authentication page shows no change to the email.

Edit:
The code above is working as far as I can tell. However, it presents another issue with UI.
If the user did click on the verification link, then the data in Firestore and Firebase Auth are matching and everything is good. But if he didn't, then there's a mismatch in the data stored.
The Firestore will have the new email, while Firebase Auth will have the old email. As I'm presenting the user with his email address in the profile, this is not good.
If there's a way to detect the email change in Firebase Auth (or when the user verifies the new email)?, then I can listen to this change and update the Firestore data then.
The emailVerified field of the "User" class, is a bool and not a stream I can subscriber to.



Now that updateEmail is deprecated for updating Firebase user's email.

Indeed the User#updateEmail() function is deprecated.

How to update the user's email?

As the official documentation says, the function that should be used in order to update an email is called User#verifyBeforeUpdateEmail() which:

Sends a verification email to a new email address. The user's email will be updated to the new one after being verified.

You say:

It worked one time for unknown magical reasons, but never since.

Such an operation:
await userAuth.user?.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(newEmail);

Might fail, due to many reasons. A good thing to do in such a case is to handle errors. So I recommend you to do that, otherwise, you'll never know when an operation fails and more importantly, why it failed.

I'm getting an exception that the user cannot be found.

If you're trying to update the email address of a user that doesn't exist, such an error will be thrown.

Thank you for your reply Alex. I understand the flow of this new process now. I'm having another UI issue because of this process. If the user did click on the verification link, then the data in Firestore and Firebase Auth are matching and everything is good. But if he didn't, then there's a mismatch in the data stored. Is there anyway to detect the email change in Firebase Auth (or when the user verifies the new email)?. The emailVerified in the User is a bool and not a stream I can subscriber to.

I think that this approach answers your question.

Hey there. Did my answer/comment help? Can I help you with other information?
